# What is the relation between C++ standard library and system interface standards like POSIX?

Tags: c++, posix, std

Recently I got a question from a colleague whether Dinkumware C++ standard library supports POSIX and I don't know how to answer that. To me it is not clear what is the relation between the two.

Does the C++ standard library provide implementations for POSIX interfaces? Or the two actually two separate things that don't correlate with each other but can be used in tandem during development?

I did some googling but cannot really draw any conclusion. There is this article describing the difference between POSIX and standard C, but what about C++ standard libraries?
[Difference Between POSIX and Standard C Library](http://www.thejaywalker.net/2010/12/difference-between-posix-and-standard-c.html)

Any enlightenment would be appreciated!

Comment: They lie on two different levels of abstraction. The C++ Standard Library is implemented *over* POSIX.

Comment: You need to separate concepts a bit. First of all, there's the formal *specification* of the C standard library, the C++ standard library and POSIX; this specification just says what functionality should be made available to the user by any *implementation* of such a specification. Any particular *implementation* can then choose what to support from which specifications. For instance, various `Visual C++` versions has only partial support for the C++ standard library and at least some support for the POSIX extensions.

Comment: So on the specification level, the standard libraries and POSIX are separate entities, but the C++ specification refers to the C specification and the POSIX specification refers to the C specification (and maybe C++ too, I don't know). Then there's the implementation level of any particular vendor/source and that can mix and match as it sees fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> whether Dinkumware C++ standard library supports POSIX ... To me it is not clear what is the relation between the two.

POSIX is the standard for operating system interface. The C++ standard library is not an operating system, so this question needs to be elaborated.

The C++ standard library does not require POSIX, POSIX does not require C++ standard library. However, the C++ standard requires a few things to be compatible with POSIX:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace posix or to a namespace within namespace posix unless otherwise specified. The namespace posix is reserved for use by ISO/IEC 9945 and other POSIX standards.
>
> The global namespace posix is now reserved for standardization. Valid C ++ 2003 code that uses a top-level namespace posix may be invalid in this International Standard.
>
> For operating systems that are based on POSIX, implementations are encouraged to define the std::system_category() values as identical to the POSIX errno values, with additional values as de- fined by the operating system’s documentation. Implementations for operating systems that are not based on POSIX are encouraged to define values identical to the operating system’s values. For errors that do not originate from the operating system, the implementation may provide enums for the associated values.
>
> Calls to the POSIX functions setenv and putenv modify the environment.
>
> The header `<cerrno>` is described in Table 43. Its contents are the same as the POSIX header `<errno.h>`, except that errno shall be defined as a macro. [ Note: The intent is to remain in close alignment with the POSIX standard. — end note ]
>
> streamsize is used in most places where ISO C would use size_t. Most of the uses of streamsize could use size_t, except for the strstreambuf constructors, which require negative values. It should probably be the signed type corresponding to size_t (which is what Posix.2 calls ssize_t).
>
> Specifies that the grammar recognized by the regular expression engine shall be that used by basic regular expressions in POSIX, Base Definitions and Headers, Section 9, Regular Expressions.

Although POSIX is based on C standard library and defers to it, and C standard library is a part of C++ language specification, the C++ standard library normally does not implement the C standard library.

The C standard library, on the other hand, may implement functionality that POSIX requires. A few quotes from [The New C Standard: An Economic and Cultural Commentary](http://www.knosof.co.uk/cbook/cbook.html):

> Some of the functions in the C library have the same name as functions defined by POSIX. POSIX, being an API-based standard (essentially a complete operating system) vendors have shown more interest in implementing the POSIX functionality.
>
> Most hosted environments provide the full set of functionality specified here. The POSIX (ISO/IEC 9945) standard defines some of the functions in the C library. On the whole the specification of this functionality is a pure extension of the C specification.
>
> The C Standard, unlike POSIX, does not prohibit the use of functions, macros, type definitions, and objects from other standards, but such libraries must not change the behavior of any of the C-defined library functionality.
>
> On most implementations a byte occupies 8 bits. The POSIX Standard requires that CHAR_BIT have a value of 8. The Digital DEC 10 and Honeywell/Multics used a 36-bit word with the underlying storage organization based on 9-bit bytes. Some DSP chips have a 16- or 32-bit character type (this often has more to do with addressability issues than character set sizes).
>
> Structure or union types defined in system headers are special in that development projects rarely have any control over their contents. The members of structure and union types defined in these system headers can vary between vendors. An example of the different structure members seen in the same structure type is provided by the dirent structure. The POSIX.1 Standard requires that this structure type include the members d_name and d_namelen. The Open Groups Single Unix Specification goes further and requires that the member d_ino must also be present. Looking at the system header on Linux we find that it also includes the members d_off and d_type;...

Comment: "The relation between the C++ standard library and POSIX is weak: they co-exist" - and this coexistence is required during development because the C++ standard library does not cover everything the OS has to offer, like threading, sockets, etc.?

Comment: Chose this as the answer as it gives the most clarity on my doubts.

Comment: @SuryaWijayaMadjid Added a few quotes for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that C++ standard library and C standard library operates exactly on same level. That means that you find there utilities that allow to do potentially complex operations, but with little requirement on underlying OS - procisely because they have to be portable across all architectures.

Posix on the other side deals with OS layer. So IMHO, almost all that is written in the referenced article applies to C++ standard library as well. The main difference comes from the fact that it is now a **C++** library vs. a **C** Posix one., that means that in addition to portability, you also gain type control, overrides and all other C++ goodies.

Comment: "...in addition to portability, you also gain type control, overrides and all other C++ goodies" you mean if I develop using C++ standard (not POSIX), right?

Comment: @SuryaWijayaMadjid: I mean that many things that standard C or C++ library do could alse be done at Posix level (file io among others). But using C++ library instead of Posix function gives better portability, type control and ...

Answer (score 1):

POSIX specifically incorporates the C standard up to 2004 by reference:

> The facilities provided in POSIX.1-2008 are drawn from the following base documents: […]
>
> ISO/IEC 9899:1999, Programming Languages - C, including ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.1:2001(E), ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.2:2004(E), and ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3

It additionally incorporates the Fortran-78 standard, without defining system interfaces, and says, “Additional language bindings and development utility options may be provided in other related standards or in a future version.”  On most real systems, there is a single "C library" that contains all the bindings from both standards.

Maxim Egorushkin has some examples of language standards that try to be compatible with POSIX.

POSIX is unusual in that it adds new features and guarantees to standard system headers.  Most system libraries are more separate from the standard library than that: if you write a program for Windows, you include both `<windows.h>` and the standard library headers.  C library functions link to the MSVC runtime DLL, while system calls link to KERNEL, GDI, etc.  Generally, though, you would need to use the system and standard libraries provided by your compiler together, and link to its runtime.