# Using POSIX feature test macros with C++

Tags: c++, posix

When I'm building POSIX C programs, I want to be portable and use only POSIX or standard C library functions.  So, for example, with gcc or clang, I build like this:

`gcc -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`

Setting the standard to C99 removes all extensions, then `_XOPEN_SOURCE` exposes POSIX interfaces. I no longer have the environment polluted with extensions from GNU, BSD, etc.

However, the waters seem murkier with C++. I want to do this:

`g++ -std=c++14 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`

This has worked fine for me on various operating systems: Linux/glibc, Haiku, MinGW, macOS, at least. But apparently, there are problems with POSIX feature test macros and C++. [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37853/c-plus--plus--7.html) have this to say:

> C++ bindings are not defined for POSIX or SUSv4, so specifying feature test macros such as _POSIX_SOURCE, _POSIX_C_SOURCE, and _XOPEN_SOURCE can result in compilation errors due to conflicting requirements of standard C++ and these specifications.

While I don't have a copy of Oracle Solaris, I am seeing issues with FreeBSD and OpenBSD.

On FreeBSD:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { }
```

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14  -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L t.cpp
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:631:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'isascii'
        return isascii(__c) ? (__tab_[static_cast<int>(__c)] & __m) !=0 : false;
...
```

(This builds fine with `_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`). C++ headers on FreeBSD use `isacii`, a non-standard function, so it's not exposed when `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is set.

Or on OpenBSD:

```
#include <fstream>
int main() { }
```

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 t.cpp
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/fstream:183:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:32:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/support/newlib/xlocale.h:25:
/usr/include/c++/v1/support/xlocale/__strtonum_fallback.h:23:64: error: unknown type name 'locale_t'
                                                char **endptr, locale_t) {
```

Presumably `<locale.h>` isn't getting included somewhere it “should” be.

The worrisome conclusion I'm drawing is that you can't portably have a POSIX C++ environment that is free of non-POSIX extensions. These examples work fine on OpenBSD and FreeBSD if the feature test macros are removed. That looks to be because the BSD headers expose BSD functions unless in standard C mode, but they do not care about standard C++ mode (they explicitly check whether macros corresponding to C89, C99, or C11 are set). glibc looks to be the same: it still exposes non-standard C functions in standard C++ mode, so perhaps it's only a matter of time before I run into a build error there.

So the actual question is this: can you write portable POSIX C++ code which does *not* expose platform-specific functionality? Or if I'm targeting POSIX with C++ should I just not set any feature test macros and hope for the best?

EDIT:

I got to thinking about the implications of this (as in, why do I care?), and the following program, I think, illustrates it. This is Linux/glibc:

```
#include <ctime>
int dysize;
```

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++14 t.cpp
t.cpp:2:5: error: ‘int dysize’ redeclared as different kind of entity
    2 | int dysize;
      |     ^~~~~~
In file included from t.cpp:1:
/usr/include/time.h:262:12: note: previous declaration ‘int dysize(int)’
  262 | extern int dysize (int __year) __THROW  __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

This is the standard `<ctime>` header, which is does *not* include anything called `dysize`.  That's an old SunOS function that glibc includes for compatibility. A C program built with `-std=c99` won't expose it, but C++ always does. And there's no real way of knowing which non-reserved identifiers will be used by various implementations. If `-std=c++14` caused non-standard identifiers to be hidden, that would avoid this problem, but it doesn't, and I can't see a way around that.

Which might imply that the feature test macro is a red herring: the source of the problem is that, on at least some real-world implementations, C++ compilers are exposing symbols they're not supposed to.

Comment: Related/relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33776503/10871073

Comment: I think that answer, while useful, is more about what's required from C++ to be compatible with POSIX; but not as much about _how_ to mix POSIX and C++ in a portable way. This did make me think of something related to my question that is probably worth adding in an edit, so I'll do that now.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it as a duplicate - just thought it may be useful. I'm glad it was.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to build a toolchain, and work from that with the libraries, includes, the correct compiler (perhaps a stripped version that can only use POSIX libraries, includes, etc).

To make it portable, generally you would build the application using static linkers. Other linker options may be necessary that point specifically or include your toolchain environment paths.

And if you're using POSIX threads, you may need -pthread.

I see that you are using system-wide headers and libraries, when really, you probably want a specific to your POSIX application toolchain, to avoid contamination.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. How would you build a stripped-down version of the toolchain that only includes POSIX features and not other system-specific ones? For example, I don't think that glibc has any option to do that.

Comment: You're including system wide headers. If that's causing you problems, build a toolchain with the appropriate headers and applications needed to build your program. If you need to build glibc, look at the options. You may have to pass lots of --disable to the configure script. If that doesn't work, you can build a jail or chroot environment.  You can copy and paste certain libraries and headers, you don't need the whole thing. Use what your program needs if you want to build a POSIX compliant portable application.  Old versions of gcc may be more friendly to your coding style as well.